# Problems to insert a Countdown timer [android studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

I'm trying to insert a CountDown Timer in my code, but I don't know what I'm making wrong, because there are many errors in any lines marked by red.

I need a Countdown that starts with 00:15 seconds until 00:00. I searched any codes (includes the code from Developer Android, but nothing works well.

This is my code below and I don't know where I insert the Countdown Timer code.
Anyone can helps me?

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.pandaeducation.masterofmath;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int correctAnswer;
    Button buttonObjectChoice1;
    Button buttonObjectChoice2;
    Button buttonObjectChoice3;
    TextView textObjectPartA;
    TextView textObjectPartB;
    TextView textObjectScore;
    TextView textObjectLevel;

    int currentScore = 0;
    int currentLevel = 1;
    private int answerGiven;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //The next line loads our UI design to the screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //*Here we get a working object based on either the button or TextView class
        // and base as well as link our new objects
        // directly to the appropriate UI elements that we created previously*/
        textObjectPartA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
        textObjectPartB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartB);
        textObjectScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        textObjectLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLevel);
        buttonObjectChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
        buttonObjectChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
        buttonObjectChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);

        //Now we use the setText method of the class on our objects
        //to show our variable values on the UI elements.
        buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonObjectChoice2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonObjectChoice3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }//onCreate ends here


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //declare a new int to be used in all the cases
        int answerGiven = 0;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonChoice1:
                //initialize a new int with the value contained in buttonObjectChoice1
                //remember we put it there ourselves previously
                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice1.getText());

                break;
            case R.id.buttonChoice2:
                //same as previous case but using the next button
                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice2.getText());

                break;
            case R.id.buttonChoice3:
                //same as previous case but using the next button
                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice3.getText());

                break;

        }

        updateScoreAndLevel(answerGiven);
        setQuestion();
    }


    void setQuestion() {
        //Generate the parts of the question
        int numberRange = currentLevel * 3;
        Random randInt = new Random();

        int partA = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
        partA++;//don't want a zero value

        int partB = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
        partB++;//dont't want a zero value

        correctAnswer = partA * partB;
        int wrongAnswer1 = correctAnswer - 2;
        int wrongAnswer2 = correctAnswer + 2;

        textObjectPartA.setText("" + partA);
        textObjectPartB.setText("" + partB);

        //set the multichoice buttons
        //A number between 0 and 2
        int buttonLayout = randInt.nextInt(3);
        switch (buttonLayout) {
            case 0:
                buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + correctAnswer);
                buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
                buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
                break;
            case 1:
                buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + correctAnswer);
                buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
                buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
                break;
            case 2:
                buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + correctAnswer);
                buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
                buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
                break;
        }

    }

    void updateScoreAndLevel(int answerGiven) {

        if (isCorrect(answerGiven)) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= currentLevel; i++) {
                currentScore = currentScore + i;
            }

            currentLevel++;
        } else {
            currentScore = 0;
            currentLevel = 1;
        }

        //Actually update the two TextViews
        textObjectScore.setText("Score: " + currentScore);
        textObjectLevel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);
    }

    boolean isCorrect(int answerGiven) {
        boolean correctTrueOrFalse;
        if (answerGiven == correctAnswer) {//WAY!
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well Done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            correctTrueOrFalse = true;
        } else {//Uh-oh!
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Duh! Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            correctTrueOrFalse = false;
        }
        return correctTrueOrFalse;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are the steps to add count down functionality using a handler. 
Create a  class MyTimer that extends Runnable and inside it add the following
Declare variable

```
private long timeRemaining;
private Handler handler;
```

Constructor

```
public MyTimer(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
        // timer gets 15 sec or 15000 milliseconds
        this.timeRemaining = 15000;
    }
```

Override run method

```
   @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!isKilled) {
            Log.d("TAG", "run was called, time reamaining " + timeRemaining / 1000);

            timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1000;

            if (timeRemaining >= 0) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                //do something like calling a method
            }
        }
    }
```

In MainActivity add the following as class variables

```
private Handler mCurrentHandler;
private MyTimer timer;
```

In onCreate method add

```
mCurrentHandler = new Handler();
timer = new MyTimer(mCurrentHandler);
```

Finally add the following wherever u want so that the count down begins

```
timer.setTimeRemaining(MyTimer.convertToMilliseconds(input));
timer.start();
```